# Any good ideas for drawing 2d tile based map? (i have my own format,not Tiled"TMX")

Tags: android, 2d

```
    for(int i =0;i<element[id].Element.length;i++)//SCAN EACH MAMBER OF THIS ELEMENT
    {
    dRectangle =
        new Rect((int)(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x + elementSize.x),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y + elementSize.y));

    if(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x <= SCREEN_WIDTH + lementSize.x&&
        element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x<=-elementSize.x)
  if(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y <= SCREEN_HEIGHT + elementSize.y&&element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y<=-elementSize.y)//----- now the element is inbounds the screen.Draw it;
    canvas.drawBitmap(ElemtMap.getBmap(), sRectangle,dRectangle, null);*/
    }

    //TODO: DECIDE WHICH SPRITE TO DRAW
    // HOW MANY TIMES WE ARE GOING TO DRAW SAME SPRITE (AND POSITION);
    /*
     * 
     * for(int i =0;i<How_Many_Time_This_Element_Used;i++)<----scan all
     *  {
     * if(the sprite is inbounds screen)<------sprite[id].position;
     * draw(ELEMENT ID,ElementPosition[i]);
     * 
     * }
     * 
     */
    canvas.restore();
}
```

this is how i draw the sprit.
and it is veeeeery slow, like hell.

First, I've read the map and get [How many elements do we have in the elementMap].
And then i have created an Single_element class to store each element,and how many times
this element used,and each position.

Then,now i've got the number of total element, i created element[total_element]
use. I have to scan each element to decide which element to draw, how many times 
to draw it,and where to draw.

then,my game beceme veeeeeeeeeerryyy  sllloooooowww:(
i know this is a BAD way to draw.
so, is there any idea ,example or whatever to deal with [Draw tiled map]?

I've downloaded and checked AndEngine. nothing helped.:S(or maybe im too stupid to understand XD)
thanks!

Edit: it is

```
dRectangle =
        new Rect((int)(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x + elementSize.x),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y + elementSize.y));
```

slow my game down:S `

Answer (score 0):

You are likely feeling the effect of instantiating and garbage collecting a big number of Rect objects.

Each iteration causes a number of Rect objects to be instantiated and discarded and the Garbage collection pauses affect the speed and smoothness of your application. In games programming on android it is often necessary to reuse objects rather than instantiate new for this very reason, although it is better programming practice in general to avoid mutable objects.

In you case, if my theory is right you can solve this by instantiating a new Rect assign to dRectangle before the loop;

```
Rect dRectangle = new Rect();
```

then use the set method to change its values on each iteration. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#set(int, int, int, int)

```
dRectangle.set((int)(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].x + WorldPos.x + elementSize.x),
        (int)(element[id].Element[i].y + WorldPos.y + elementSize.y));
```

I´d also ask you to reconsider AndEngine, though that was not your question :-)

Answer (score -1):

1) Some art of mapping with SpriteName->Sprite

2) Load description with Map

3) Find what rect of world should be drawn

4) Draw background. If you store Bg in 2d char array, it's pretty fast. So e.g. W is water, S is Sand Then if you have array like this:

```
SSWSWSSS
SSWSWSSS
SSWWWSSS
SSSSWSSS
SSSSWSSS
```

itereate over array once. and for every Char you find in mapping S->sand.png, W->water.png

Then draw game objects. They are typical stored in a ArrayList. Just make AABB test, wheather go should be drawn and draw if needed.
Or use sweep and prune, quadtree for that.

P.S. I do not understand your code.